# Personal finance application

Tags: linux, offline, finance

I have to manage my (& my families) personal finance situation. This includes expected income, expected payments, savings, loans etc.

I don't need some full fledged financing application like GnuCash and it isn't used for "official" stuff like taxes etc. (More precisely I use it to estimate my taxes but the actual amount of that is calculated by my bookkeeper, so I don't need to worry about the accuracy of my over the thumb calculations)

Must haves:

- Multiple areas of expenses, flags are fine. (e.G. Car, Private, Tax, Medical)
- Repeating expenses (rent, loans, telephone)
- Estimation of future (I don't need fancy graphs, but I want to scroll to 'next year, same month' and see how much money there should be.
- Linux. Preferably XFCE compatible (GTK+) but I take Gnome/KDE stuff as well if necessary.
- Windows tools only if they are **known** to run smooth via wine, I don't want to test that.
- Offline. No webapp or something.
- Below 100€ for ownership (No "just one computer license" or something)

Nice to have:

- Multiple banking accounts (e.G. Giro, Credit Card, Savings)
- Statistics. In the end of the year I want to know how much money did I spend on my car, my doctor... whatever.
- Import of CSV from my bank accounts. I need to be able to manually assign each line to a specific area then.
- Calculations. (In this month I had income of 1.000€ and need to pay 19% taxes on this in three months. I can calculate that myself, but would prefer it to have that automated)
- Prognostics: I expect to spend 600€ / month on my cars and I want each month to expect that until the month is reached. Then the actual spending in this month should be decreased from that number until the end of the month is reached whereas the estimation is set to 0 and only the actual spendings are taken into consideration. I can simulate that by a recurring expense that I adjust for that month manually, but I'd rather not.
- Open Source Software so I can expand it to my needs if necessary.

Currently I use a complex Gnumeric Spreadsheet I wrote myself and expanded over the years, but this comes to its boundaries.

My current workflow is like this: When I learn about a future expense (say Taxes) I enter them into my spreadsheet and mark them in the relevant month so I won't forget to pay them. Once a month I go to my online banking system and copy/paste the entries from there into the spreadsheet.

It consists of a "general" list on the left and "specialized" areas (like car, living, private, loans, etc.) on the right where the sums from the areas on the right are referenced from the general area.

I thought about writing one of my own but before I do so I would want to know if there is something already there.

Comment: I think you may want to consider taking "Simple" out of the title this request seems a little more complex than a monthly budget organizer or something similar.  Hope you get an answer, this would be useful.

Comment: Oh and some banks actually provide some tools/information like this via their websites...something that may be worth looking into as a stopgap...

Comment: @James Compared to complex bookkeeping applications this one is quite simple. Also my bank actually does not provide any more information than it must. Unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3):

[**KMyMoney**](https://kmymoney.org/)

KMyMoney is the KDE app substitute for GnuCash but it's simpler.

- It works offline
- It works on XFCE (but you need QT libraries)
- It's free and open source
- Mulitple areas of expenses

For Repeating expenses and Estimation of future I don't know very well because I use GnuCash but it might works.

Comment: KMyMoney allows for repeated expenses, forecasting future expenses, multiple back accounts, statistics, tax calculations and more! Really love this app, thanks for the recommendation!