# Personnal finance webapp

Tags: open-source, web-apps, finance

I'm looking for a personnal finance manager webapp, open source, and with the following features :

- multiple account management
- reconcile
- categories handling

The main purpose is to host this webapp on my lan to allow my wife and I to edit and manage home budget.

I'm a [Grisbi](http://grisbi.org) big fan, but would be able to use such software from my browser.

Does it exists ?

Comment: Are you sure that you wish to store all of your personal finance data on the web without at least a few words about security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this single html file + text file you can save in dropbox/onedrive/googledrive:

http://aurelio.net/projects/moneylog/

And then update the text file, and open the html file to visualize the data.