# Best personal information managing app

Tags: finance, scheduling, todo, diary

I am looking for an app

- ability to write some to-do and categorise it
- ability to write some general information like a paragraph of notes and categorise into different category like Opinion,Observation,financial log
- ability to schedule the schedule a task

Basically the app has to be my companion.

Any ideas

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information/352#352) Then please [edit](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/49047/edit) your question. Also [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25157/personal-finances-management-calendar?rq=1) can help you to define/solve your question.

Comment: Especially missing: on what OS should it run? App could mean Android, iOS, Web-app. Then, too: what is your price margin if it comes to paid solutions – or must the app come free of charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zim Wiki](http://www.zim-wiki.org) with its [Task List Plugin](http://www.zim-wiki.org/manual/Plugins/Task_List.html). You can use Zim can be used in several different ways (Daily Journal, Getting Things Done, Creative Writing).
For to-do entries you can create checkboxes, and set tags for them, and when you open Task List window, you can filter tasks by tags.

Edit:

You can set priority for task using "!" symbol. More "!" sybols = higher priority.

Look at this [usage scenarios](http://www.zim-wiki.org/manual/Usage.html).